# How to find Red and Green Candles After crossover of EMA 6 and EMA 12 in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, candlestick-chart

I want to know whether the candles after crossover of EMA 6 and 12 are red or green.

I have written the code for the crossover also to find whether the candle is green or red after the crossover . I am having problem

```
ma = ema(close, 6)
ma2 = ema(close, 12)

aboveMa = crossover(ma,ma2)

// TO FIND THE NEXT CANDLE 
threeAboveMa1 = aboveMa[1]

open[threeAboveMa1] 
close[threeAboveMa1]
```

it is showing error

Comment: Normally, it would be helpful if you can share the error message when asking questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is, just find out whether the current bar is green or red and see if ma crossover happened **one bar ago**. You can use `[]` operator to access historical values.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
ma = ta.ema(close, 6)
ma2 = ta.ema(close, 12)
aboveMa = ta.crossover(ma,ma2)    
greenCandle = aboveMa[1] and (close >= open)
redCandle = aboveMa[1] and (open > close)

plot(greenCandle ? 1 : 0, color=color.green)
plot(redCandle ? 1 : 0, color=color.red)
```